# Issue reading file to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, io, filestream

I'm maintaining a program that has the following code to read a file to a byte array:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    fileStream.Position = 0;

    int fileSize = (int)fileStream.Length;
    int readSize;
    int remain = fileSize;
    var pos = 0;

    byteData = new byte[fileSize];

    while (remain > 0)
    {
        readSize = fileStream.Read(byteData, pos, Math.Min(1024, remain));
        pos += readSize;
        remain -= readSize;
    }
}
```

And then afterwards outputs this byte array as a Base64 string:

```
var value = "File contents:" + Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToBase64String(byteData)
```

The issue we are occasionally seeing is that the output is just a string of A's, like "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", but longer.  I've figured out that if you output a byte array that has been initialized to a given length but not assigned a value (i.e. each byte is still the initial value of 0) it will output in Base64 as a series of A's, so my hypothesis is that the byte array is being created to the size of the file, but then the value of each byte isn't being assigned.  Looking at the code I can't see any obvious issues with it though, so if anyone knows better I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Your `byteData` array is initialized to the size of `fileSize`, which is the length of the entire file. Doing this defeats the purpose of loading the file in chunks like how you are doing. Either initialize your array to the chunk size (which appears to be 1024 in your code) or just use `File.ReadAllBytes`.

Comment: @Abion47 The point of the code is to have an byte array containing the entire contents of the file, so of course it first initializes the array to the length of the entire file.  I don't know why it is limiting the block size to a max of 1024 bytes though.  File.ReadAllBytes might well be an alternative (and simpler) method for reading the contents of the file, but unless I can get an idea of the reason for the issue I'm hesitant to change production code without a good reason.

Comment: It's limiting the block size to 1024 because that's the number in the `length` parameter of `fileStream.Read`. But that method is for reading files portions of a time. If your goal is to just read the entire file into a single array, then this approach is overkill, and I'd recommend simply using `File.ReadAllBytes`. That being said, your approach is also ideal for if you're using the value of `pos` as input for a progress bar.

Comment: @Abion47 I meant I don't know why the author of the code decided to limit the block size.  But no, not using `pos` for a progress bar, so `File.ReadAllBytes` certainly seems like a better solution because it is much simpler.  But like I said, unless there is some reason to think the existing code is defective (as opposed to just overkill) I'm still hesitant to change it.

Comment: Four reasons to change the code: 1) it is overkill for the job; 2) it adds a certain amount of overhead to the operation; 3) the added complexity doesn't offer any additional benefits to offset the complexity cost; 4) it occasionally produces erroneous output. That would be enough for me.

Comment: If nothing else, find a file that consistently returns the string of "A"s and test it out with the `File.ReadAllBytes` option.

Comment: Reasons 1-3 are good reasons to fix code that is in development, not good enough reasons to change code in production.  Reason 4 is not certain.  Also, unfortunately I don't have access to the files on users' PCs and haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself yet, so I can't do a compare with 'File.ReadAllBytes'.  I may end up changing it still, but I'd love to be a little more certain of what the issue actually is.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you, then. You can't be *positive* about what is causing the bad output until you have access to a file that reliably produces it, and maybe not even then depending on the exact cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I did end up changing it to `File.ReadAllBytes`, however I also found out that the issue was with the file itself, and an empty byte array was actually correct.  I.e. each byte was still the initial value of 0, so a corresponding base64 string of "A"s was also correct.